# do not allow {} as request body

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, http-post, jackson-databind

I have the following post method handler:

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public int myEndpoint(@RequestBody MyBody body) {
    return body.foo;
}
```

Which accepts the following request body:

```
class MyBody {
    private int foo;

    public MyBody() {}

    public MyBody(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

Now, I expect that when I make request to `/endpoint` with body `{}` It'll return status 400,

but I get 200 and `body.foo` is 0.

How can I make sure `{}` body is rejected?

Comment: Firstly, change your primitive values like `int` to `Integer`. Secondly you can use validation like @Airy said or use `Optional`.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could validate the body with annotations :

```java
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public int myEndpoint(@RequestBody @Valid MyBody body) {
    return body.foo;
}
```

you also need to add validations dependencie

```xml
<dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

then `MyBody` is a DTO, don't use primitive types as int since they have a default value. Add the validations you need :

```java
class MyBody {
    @NotNull
    private Integer foo;

    ...
}
```

Comment: The `@NotNull` before the body parameter is redunant. It doesn't affect anything and `@RequestBody` anonation is required=true by default.